clone of Vmware VM fails with "error caused by file" (vmdk)
I am attempting to clone a VM. Using ESX 5.5 and vCenter.
I get cloning fails reported by vCenter with:
"Error caused by file: /vmfs/volumes/57fd0830-5fc3a738-af44-002590fe0960/Linux Toolbox/Linux Toolbox-000002.vmdk"
If I check that vmdk with vmkfstools i get following:
/vmfs/volumes/57fd0830-5fc3a738-af44-002590fe0960/Linux ToolBox # vmkfstools -x check "Linux ToolBox-000002.vmdk"
Disk is error free
The 00002.vmdk seems to be part of a snapshot but I see no snapshots in Snapshot manager.
Also i notice that the Vcenter has a warning under alarms tab saying:
"Virtual machine Consolidation Needed status"
However, when I try Snapshot>Consolidate under vCenter it fails with this error:

The machine does boot fine. The host had a few ungraceful power offs which could have caused this issue.
I am showing the files under this vm folder:

Any suggestions much appreciated.

What's the smart status of the drives? In addition 5.5 is ancient....

i am not sure how to get the "smart status" of the drives. yeah i know it's ancient but i see no reason to upgrade really. it works. if it weren't for power issues the vms are working fine for 8 years straight.

https://www.ubackup.com/enterprise-backup/vmware-esxi-check-disk-health.html - and a good reason to update would be for instance bug fixes and security fixes...

It it were working fine, why are you having any questions? Anyway, we believe using outdated and unsupported environments, like ancient and abandoned hardware and software, is not a reasonable IT management practice and this makes your question off topic.

It's not off topic. If you don't want to answer a question on older systems just go to questions on newer ones.
Come on. It had like 5 ungraceful shutdowns it's irrelevant what version you run in that scenario. One of the NICs eeprom got wiped out - no MAC addresses. Had to replace. Surely you cannot expect esx 5.5 to handle that better than a newer version. I am sure you know better than that.

For anybody who is facing similar problem I ended up doing a file backup of the linux vm from the OS and then created a new one from scratch and restored from backup.  Perhaps some file somewhere could be bad but I have not seen any issues so far.

@vidarlo quite obviously. but not if you are not impacted by the bugs that are being patched.
